# For power loss, P=I^2R, why can't I use I=V/R to find I and put it into P=I^2R

Tags: voltage, power, current

To calculate power loss using P=I^2R, we cannot use I=V/R, to find current and plug it into P=I^2R, instead we must use P=IV to find current, is there a reason why?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you asking how to solve elementary school equations? P=IU is the same as P=I^2 R. Since U=IR, then P=IIR.

Comment: This question sounds quite similar to this one: [Power loss during transmission](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125737/power-loss-during-transmission)

Comment: Or why not use \$P = \frac{V^2}{R}\$? It's all the same formula spun around by ohms law.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is v in p=IV if I want to use p=IV to calculate power loss](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452212/what-is-v-in-p-iv-if-i-want-to-use-p-iv-to-calculate-power-loss)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one, I=V/R is only valid for resistors, so as a general definition of power it is better to go with P=IV which applies regardless of component.

a schematic or an explanation of the actual situation would get you better answers.

That said,  defining power with P=IV is more general so it is better in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. If you plug I = V/R into P = IV, you just get P = V^2 / R. You could calculate the value of I and then plug it in, or you can solve it symbolically and possibly save a few steps.